# In TypeScript, how do I call a method by its name if this name is also an argument?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

Is it possible to define `Qux` here in such a way as to avoid the error? I tried defining it as a mapped type, but with no luck.

```
interface Qux {
  foo(stuff: string[], key: 'foo'): number;
  bar(stuff: string[], key: 'bar'): boolean;
  // ... more methods like that, with different return types ...
}

declare const q: Qux;

function baz<K extends keyof Qux>(key: K) {
  return q[key](
    [],
    key // ERROR: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
  );
}

const b = baz('foo'); // needs to be number
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIoFcAeyDeBYAKGWRgHtSAKAZzHRhgC5kapQBzAbQF0AaZAawgBPJgHIypUQEomIdAFsARtADchYorhRqtekxbtufQSOSjNUaU0XkANhDgg1RZAHpXyAHTfk80lBR5CDAAC1IAEypkW2BBZFC4MD4Ad2BQ5HDgemgIcGQA2igQeKEABwgo709CAF9CQnCIBFstFARSEBpkAEcmDExnQhh0EAQwYA7kTQAvAB4AaWQITEgQSIFhUhg0LAA%20ChMmealcdXzg9CKejhMuCjPiIweNoTcPAFEAJU%20AeU%20mAAqZRQogMIDYomQwCiIFIYGQcCoVGAbBAcEU9nipBK5TMIAgADdoKIzlJnHUCIR2p14YpkABeKZwaYUcTkaQqN7IfEQdZgbHKbkKZRQIA)

Comment: Remove the `k` from the `declare` statement and assign it an actual value, e.g. `const k: keyof Qux = 'foo';`. The error will be gone.

Comment: I don't know the value of `k` beforehand. It comes from elsewhere.

Comment: How is `k` imported into this script where the interface `Qux` is defined?

Comment: It's passed as a function parameter

Comment: I updated the code to make this more clear

Comment: The only way I know of to do this is to refactor to use generic indexed access types as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  For your example code that looks like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WGX00w). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Wow. Yes, it works for me. Somehow I missed such a simple way to write a mapped type. My attempts were a bit more complex. In particular they had `-?`, which disabled this special behavior that you refer to. Would love to see an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript can't follow arbitrary higher-order type relationships. You want the compiler to notice that for any key `K` in `keyof Qux`, the method at `Qux[K]` will accept an argument list of type `[string[], K]` and produce a corresponding output type.  But it doesn't abstract over `K extends keyof Qux` that way by itself.

The only way I know of to get this working (without using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions), which is often the *easiest* way to proceed but gives up compiler-verified type safety) is to refactor to using [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into a simple "base" interface type or to [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that base interface.  This is described in detail inside [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) and is the recommended approach to getting the compiler to notice such relationships.

So we need to rewrite `Qux` as a mapped type over a basic interface, like this:

```
interface QuxMapper {
  foo: number;
  bar: boolean;
}

type Qux = {
  [K in keyof QuxMapper]: (stuff: string[], key: K) => QuxMapper[K]
}
```

This might look like a no-op, since the new definition of `Qux` is equivalent to old definition.  Indeed if you use IntelliSense to inspect it, the type is basically the same:

```
/* type Qux = {
    foo: (stuff: string[], key: "foo") => number;
    bar: (stuff: string[], key: "bar") => boolean;
} */
```

But the crucial difference is the representation.  The new `Qux` is explicitly defined in terms of `K` in `keyof QuxMapper` and each property is of a corresponding type that depends on `K`.

Now things just work as desired:

```
declare const q: Qux;
function baz<K extends keyof Qux>(key: K) {
  return q[key]([], key);
}   
baz('foo').toFixed(); // okay
baz('bar') === true // okay
```

That's because inside the function implementation, the type `Qux[K]` of `q[key]` is transformed to `(stuff: string[], key: K) => QuxMapper[K]`.  That's a single call signature, and it accepts the arguments `[]` and `key` because they are known to be of the right types (with `key` of type `K` being the important bit).  So the call succeeds.  And the return type of the function is `QuxMapper[K]` for the same reason.

So when you call `baz('foo')` you get a `number` and when you call `baz('bar')` you get a `boolean`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIoFcAeBZOAHPaZAbwFgAoZZGAexoC5kR0BbAI2gG4Kq24pGbOgBsIcEN3IBfChTABPQmizIAvCR7IA2gGlkoZAGsI8mjGU58hKAF1GACgDOYdDBiNnUUAHMtNgDRGJow6AJRqAHwWuATQujYUMuQUAPQAVMgKShiYahqUVNR0Ds6u7siePn6BxvKMAES0NPXhqlHM7FyavPwlLm4eYF4gvgFBdcj1fFAtkchCNKLiklLIaSmyyeQAJhAIwvwoCDQgzsgAjow5kjDoIAhgwCfzcABeADx6EJiQINuO4zMFgi9lqIXCZAKUAgLigIAuWlqNns1XGoRWmz4r3sAHImjjQgA6MA0ABiwEwEG29nRyBSKWQNEMcHkFCxuOmBLUqnUQ3QKHpjOZrPIQA)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply specify the correct function return type (and cast `fn` to `any`)

```js
interface Qux {
  foo(stuff: string[], key: 'foo'): number;
  bar(stuff: string[], key: 'bar'): boolean;
  // ... more methods like that, with different return types ...
}

declare const q: Qux;

function baz<K extends keyof Qux>(key: K): Qux[K] {
  const fn =  q[key] as any;
  return fn([], key);
}

const f = baz('foo'); // number
const b = baz('bar'); // boolean
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIoFcAeyDeBYAKGWRgHtSAKAZzHRhgC5kapQBzAbQF0AaZAawgBPJgHIypUQEomIdAFsARtADchYorhRqtekxbtufQSOSjNUaU0XkANhDgg1RZAHpXyAHTfk80lBR5CDAAC1IAEypkW2BBZFC4MD4Ad2BQ5HDgemgIcGQA2igQeKEABwgo709CAF9CQnCIBFstFARSEBpkAEcmDExnQhh0EAQwYA7kTQAvAB4AaWQITEgQSIFhUhg0LAA+ChMmeZkdzA55rlx1ZHbOsBJigF5ibo4TS7goxyFnYgL0IoPChGDZCKTOOoEQi3LrbZ4zCjicjSFRuDxyJTQaEdLqKZDwuDTREWFFoqZ2BwgIA)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing now. Just wanted to check if there is a more strongly typed solution

Comment: @thorn0 I don't think it's the same. In your code, the result type of `baz('foo')` is `number | boolean`

Comment: I mean my real project code

Comment: @thorn0 And how should we know what your "real project code" is when you don't post it here? :D

Comment: You shouldn't. The question is self-sufficient. I'm just saying I'm aware of this solution, which is basically the good old "use `any` to make errors go away"

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the functions `foo` and `bar` with a [generic parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) that `extends keyof Qux` and use that generic argument as a type for your function parameter `key`.

```
interface Qux {
  foo<T extends keyof Qux>(stuff: string[], key: T): number;
  bar<T extends keyof Qux>(stuff: string[], key: T): boolean;
}

declare const q: Qux, k: keyof Qux;

q[k]([], "foo");
q[k]([], "bar");
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIoFcAeyDeBYAKGWRgHtSAeAFWQk0hABMBnZAawgE9SY0sA%20ABTMw6GDABcyEVFABzANoBdADTsuUqgEopIdAFsARtADchYobhRqtehCasO3XhkxCRYydLCyQi1eqcmjrIhuQANhBwIGYEAL6EhIwQCOFWKAikICLIAI5SrmpsUk48fJixhLkKbEqCymoARGSkjVqx1bX1AY2WUG0mQA)

---

**Edit** (Thanks for the comment @Christian)

One problem here tho is that calling `foo` with a parameter `key: "bar"` will not produce a compiler error. To avoid this you'd have to runtime check the union to narrow the type to a literal.

```
k === "foo" && q[k]<typeof k>([], "bar"); // "bar" not assignable to "foo"
```

I can't think of way without runtime check because you simply don't know the literal value of `k` at compile time, do you?

Comment: I was about to answer the same thing, but the problem is that type-checking won't alarm if `k` is `"foo"`, and the 2nd argument passed is `"bar"`, or if `k` is `"bar"` and the 2nd argument is `"foo"`.

Comment: The error is gone, but the return types are lost. We could as well write `key: keyof Qux` instead of `key: T`.

Comment: Why are the return types lost? Please take a look at [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIoFcAeyDeBYAKGWRgHtSAeAFWQk0hABMBnZAawgE9SY0sA+ABTMw6GDABcyEVFABzANoBdADTsuUqgEopIdAFsARtADchYobhRqtehCasO3XhkxCRYydLCyQi1eqcmjrIhuQANhBwIGYEAL6EhIwQCOFWKAikICLIAI5SrmpsUk48fJixhMC8gmzIALyNyABEllDNWrjmyJFgyFAQzOjhffV5CmxKFGCcAA4QZWxCymqtVh2xxAD0W8QAegD8-YPDYFJhpJHRhHFAA)

Comment: They're lost (merged) when `k` is passed directly without those `if`s. It's impractical to add identical checks for each method name. (As for the downvote, it wasn't me)

Comment: I agree that narrowing using runtime checks might be an impractical solution (especially if you have a lot of keys in `Qux) yet its the only way I can think of doing this without type assertion. Of course the return types can only be inferred if you use the checks. When not using them you don't get the correct parameter type either. I think you should go with TmTron's approach in that case.